# ST_UNION_AGG not working with window frames

Tags: google-bigquery

we are trying to do a `ST_UNION_AGG(geography) OVER (window frame)`.

But we are getting an error stating `ST_UNION_AGG is not supported`.
Anyone able to get `ST_UNION_AGG(geography) OVER a window frame? We are trying to merge polygons with each other on a specific properties.

Comment: Yep, `ST_UNION_AGG` is not supported as analytic function yet.

What kind of window do you need to use it with? Simple PARTITION BY window can be replaced by GROUP BY aggregation.

Comment: `WINDOW mywindow as (ORDER BY z DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)`. The 'z' value here is a specific number that we store along with our geometry data. The way we store our data is every row is a single polygon (it could be multi-polygon though).